# Which parameter of this JTextArea should I change?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'd like to know which parameter of my `JTextArea` I should change in order to remove this:

[image]

I want the text area to be blank and I don't want the possibility to navigate it with this brackets (?)

Comment: Do you mean to remove the Scroll Bars from the JTextArea?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to have the possibility to scroll, please be kind I'm pretty new into swing.

Comment: Why not just use a JTextField instead of the JTextArea. Is it because you need multiline support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the Scroll Bars from appearing for a JTextArea then change the Horizontal and Vertical Scroll Bar Policies for the JScrollPane that **wraps** that JTextArea:

```
jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```